# Spring Error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: > org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>

Tags: java, spring, jar, annotations, spring-3

Folks,

I am trying to run a simple spring example of using `@Required.`

But, when I run the main method class, I get below exception trace ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/util/Collection;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:750)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:175)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:485)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:716)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:377)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at
>   com.springexamples.annotation.required.EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:19)

Is there any specific jar that I am missing from classpath ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This looks very much like a version mismatch.  Are you sure that all of your Spring jars are the same version?

Comment: Do you use maven or ivy?  Is there a chance it is picking up an older version transitively?