# spring hibernate maven project gets an nosuchmethod error InjectionMetadata

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, init

I have an spring web service that uses hibernate to communicate with the postgres db this is an maven project. I was trying to get an json list when suddenly i got the following error:

## HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

**type** Exception report

**message** Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:830)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:493)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.34

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

my servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tms"/>
            <beans:property name="username" value="postgres"/>
            <beans:property name="password" value="paswoord"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="configLocation">
                <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="configurationClass">
                <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.pxl.publictms" />



</beans:beans>
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.pxl</groupId>
    <artifactId>publictms</artifactId>
    <name>PublicTms</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jackson -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1B</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
     </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And finally my controller, the methods work but when i use the getUsers method i get an http 500 error this is strange because the list is populated:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import be.pxl.publictms.model.Computer;
import be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker;
import be.pxl.publictms.service.GebruikerService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private GebruikerService gebruikerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "pc",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Computer testMethod() {
        return new Computer(0, "DELL");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Gebruiker> getUsers(){
        List<Gebruiker> users = gebruikerService.getGebruikers();
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        for(Gebruiker user: users){
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        /*List<Gebruiker> users = new ArrayList<Gebruiker>();
        users.add(new Gebruiker(1, "laurens", "test"));
        users.add(new Gebruiker(2, "laurens", "test"));
        users.add(new Gebruiker(3, "laurens", "test"));*/
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you showing us the actual `pom.xml`? The `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` class is not in any of the dependencies you've listed.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is solved now one of my dependencies had the wrong version..., do you have a clue why i get an error when i call the getUsers method? The list is populated but it won't return it...

Comment: Try asking another question, giving all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common problem is different versions of Spring libraries.
E.g. in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

and others are with:

```
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
```

Link that can help you as well:
[Spring Error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: > org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.<init>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387206/spring-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-beans-factory)

Comment: yeah i noticed it's strange because everything was 3.1.1 and now it suddenly works again... do you hav actually a clue why the method getUsers returns an http 500 with no error's my list is populated ...

Comment: What is the full URL you are calling for getUsers?

Comment: http://localhost:8084/publictms/test/users and for the testmethod http://localhost:8084/publictms/test/pc, that one returns perfect a json object

Comment: i have written a new method to handle uncaught exceptions: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker.berichtsForOntvangerid, no session or session was closed (through reference chain: be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker["berichtsForOntvangerid"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker.berichtsForOntvangerid, no session or session was closed through reference

Comment: This is Spring (Hibernate) related problem now. Here was related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795650/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection . And here you can read some useful details on it: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/111584-lazy-load-loosing-session-in-json-conversion-jackson